# Silverlight letter-spacing

Tags: c#, silverlight, fonts, kerning

What's the easiest way to manage letter-spacing, kerning or tracking in Silverlight?

I currently have big titles in Arial that just have too much space between the letters.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

dont know whether it's the best solution, but it works fine for me:

```
SomeElement.Children.Add(LetterSpacing("Test", -3));
```

...

```
private Canvas LetterSpacing(string String, double Space)
    {
        Canvas kpr = new Canvas();
        char[] lters = String.ToCharArray();
        Label[] lbls = new Label[lters.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < lters.Length; i++)
        {
            Label tmpLbl = new Label();
            lbls[i] = tmpLbl;
            kpr.Children.Add(lbls[i]);
            lbls[i].Content = lters[i];
            lbls[i].FontSize = 30;
            lbls[i].FontFamily = new FontFamily("Verdana");
        }

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            () =>
            {
                double leftPos = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < lbls.Length; j++)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(lbls[j], 0 + leftPos);
                    leftPos += (lbls[j].ActualWidth - (Space * -1));
                }
            });

        return kpr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is supported by the runtime at this time. You could export the text as a path and use that.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will write a behavior for textblock that splits all the words, with a property to assign the spacing parameter.